# Highchart - Scatter chart, points are going beyond y axis

Tags: highcharts

[image]

The points in scattered highchart is crossing y axis line. How can we resolve it?
Also, is it possible to start the highchart xaxis tick from 9:27?I tried setting xAxis: min option, but it is still starting tick position from 9:30.
this is my x and y settings:

```
xAxis: {
  type: 'datetime',
  showFirstLabel: true,
  startOnTick: false,
  endOnTick: false,
  minPadding: 0,
  maxPadding: 0,
  min: 1574654277034,    
  title: { text: 'X-Axis' },
  align: 'left'
},
yAxis: {
  lineWidth: 1,
  title: {
    text: 'Y-Axis'
  },
  opposite: false,
  gridLineColor: 'transparent',
},
```

[image]

Comment: hey, could you reproduce your case on some online editor which I could work on?

Comment: @SebastianWędzel, This is link: http://jsfiddle.net/kzpjnmto/2/. I got the issue of overlapping is due to minPadding:0. But not able to resolve startOnTick issue. The tick should start from min x value. How can we do that?

Comment: Have you tried to use plotOptions.series.pointStart? See: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.scatter.pointStart and check includes demos.

Comment: No, its not working. I tried that as well: http://jsfiddle.net/Lzau382n/

Comment: Please check it: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/4cftawzk/ I deleted min and tickPixelInterval properties from the xAxis and add a tickInterval.

Comment: It is fine, but the tickinterval is set to 2 min, which is looking very dense. Can it be same as earlier?

Comment: But how should it work in your opinion? First tick will start at 7.28 and what tickInterval should be to fit the range between the last point.

Comment: As per me, the tick should start from 7.28, then take range accordingly. i.e. 7.28, then 8.28, 9.28. For a wide screen it can be: 7.28, 7.58, 8.28, 8.58...

Comment: In this case, I advise to use tickPositioner and customize ticks positions: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/4esLwpqm/

Comment: Yes, I thought about it as the only option I can find as well. It will need to have date/time formatting manually.